# Unresponsive Contents pane in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, contents-pane

I’m having an issue where the new install of ArcGIS Pro version 2.7 isn’t responsive in certain areas. I’m using Windows 10, and my machine could handle the workload before upgrading.

Basically the Contents pane will continuously give me the loading wheel and be unable to interact with. Most buttons on the top ribbons are grayed out as well. The only things I can do are panning the map and geoprocessing tools - which are considerably faster than before. Which is good for some situations, and makes others impossible. The other GIS analyst who sits next to me also has this exact issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should go through ESRI Support so that they can investigate and fix for all users.

Comment: A network issue could cause TOC timeout. But this is more appropriate for Tech Support, since it's specific to your environment.